# How to add JavaScript code to Laravel for BackPack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel

I'm using Laravel BackPack to expedite my CRUD webapp.

I have a form with a dropdown list of users.

When a user is selected from this list, I want to populate a text box on the same form with the username of the selected user.

I normally use JavaScript to query the table and return the JSON result.

The returned data is used to populate the `#username` text box.

I am not sure where to add this JavaScript code in BackPack.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [create a new field type](http://backpackforlaravel.test/docs/3.4/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type), starting from the `select2` field (or whatever you're using now), and add your JS there.

Comment: What if wee need to simply add a littje js to add a small user interaction with the ui? cannot we simply add a js in some way to an action ?

Comment: If you want to add some JS from the controller, you can create a Widget, by creating a file inside /resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/widgets and then you can load that file using Widget::add()->type(“your-widget-name”). That blade file can hold a <script> tag with your custom JS. Alternatively, you can create a general “script” widget that loads an external js file - like we do in this PR - https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/3912

Comment: Very very limited. Are we the only with the need to simply add a small js? We actually duplicated the `create.blade.php` and the `update.blade.php` but it's very very bad as approach, because it's a long time porject and we need to keep it maintenable

Comment: I suspect you're not the only one, no. But very few people have requested this. I do not recommend overwriting the `create` or `update` blade files, that'll make it difficult to upgrade to newer versions of Backpack. Instead, I recommend you use the widget approach I told you above. Then when Backpack 4.2 rolls around, you can just delete your own widgets for this, since Backpack has them too.